# Magento 2: How to find layout position name for destination attribute of a move tag

Tags: magento2, layout

In magento2 to change a position of block `<move>` is used whose syntax is as follows.

```
<move element="name.of.an.element" destination="name.of.destination.element" as="new_alias" after="name.of.element.after" before="name.of.element.before"/>
```

I used this on some places while using this i found finding of value for  **destination**  attribute quite difficult.

Can any one please tell me how we can find value of destinations available in default magento 2 .

like **columns.top,sidebar.main,content.aside,login.content,login.header,header.panel** etc.

Answer (score 1):

Their is no as such any mechanism like path hint which helps to find the exact destination but in most of the cases the value for destination would be a class name of wrapper i.e. upper `<div>`.

[image]

We need to replace the **-** with **.** in that class name.
for ex **sidebar-main** becomes **sidebar.main**

Or you can search for sidebar.main in **vendor** directory. **sidebar.main** is nothing but a name of container.

**Note:** I am not sure if it is a actual solution or their are still some other ways to find a exact destination but as this works for me i consider this as an solution till the new exact answer will be available, for that i posted this as an answer so that it helps others.

Answer (score 0):

If you look through the layout files in the reverse order of inheritance you will see where the blocks were originally added and using which name.

Browse the layout.xml files or turn on path hints in admin.

Comment: can you please explain more in details?i am not able to  understand, tell me if need more information for my question.

Answer (score 0):

The destination should be block or container you want to include your block inside, so the destination block is the parent.

As for finding out which one to use you need to look through the related XML files, this will vary depending on which module your block is part of.